# Text substitutions for superscript and subscript

Tags: applescript, automator, text, shortcut-menu

There is a way to individually create text substitutions on Mac for most applications, by going to System Preferences→Keyboard→Text and then creating text substitutions. For example, I've made the following ones for ₂, ₃, × and ²³. [image: Text]

If I wanted to, I could create more and more shortcuts like this, but that takes a lot of time. Is there a way to use Automator and/or Applescript and/or Terminal to make such substitutions for all such cases? For example, if I type `_5002`, it should come out looking like ₅₀₀₂.

Answer (score 3):

Here is *one* solution using the command line:

1. Converting numbers to super/subscript

The `sed` utility allows you to use a translation table to convert characters to other characters:

```bsh
$ echo "abc513" | sed -e 'y|0123456789|⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹|'
abc⁵¹³

$ echo "abc513" | sed -e 'y|0123456789|₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉|'
abc₅₁₃
```

From there, we can write a `tsubst` script:

```bsh
$ cat ./tsubst
#!/bin/bash

function superscript { echo "$1" | sed -e 'y|0123456789|⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹|'; }
function subscript   { echo "$1" | sed -e 'y|0123456789|₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉|'; }

function phrase_from_shortcut_pattern {
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^\^(.+)$ ]]
  then
    # ^ -> superscript
    echo "$(superscript "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")"
  elif [[ "$1" =~ ^_(.+)$ ]]
  then
    # _ -> subscript
    echo "$(subscript "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")"
  else
    echo "$1"
  fi
}

phrase_from_shortcut_pattern "${@}"
```

That script takes one argument, a Text Replacement *shortcut pattern* with a `^` or `_` prefix to indicate a super or subscript transformation, and returns the corresponding *phrase*:

```bsh
$ ./tsubst _answer42
answer₄₂

$ ./tsubst ^answer42
answer⁴²
```

2. Generate phrases from lists or ranges of shortcut patterns

With that script, we can use `bash` loops and substitutions to generate phrases from a *list* of shortcut patterns:

```
$ for p in _42 ^42; do echo "${p} -> $(./tsubst "${p}")"; done
_42 -> ₄₂
^42 -> ⁴²
```

Or a *range* of shortcut patterns:

```
$ for p in _{6..8} ^{9..11}; do echo "${p} -> $(./tsubst "${p}")"; done
_6 -> ₆
_7 -> ₇
_8 -> ₈
^9 -> ⁹
^10 -> ¹⁰
^11 -> ¹¹
```

3. Adding text substitutions from the command line

This is the tricky part... I found *one* command-line utility that does its job well: [shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqUvq.png).

```bsh
$ shortcuts read
0: "jrv" —> "J’arrive !"
1: "omw" —> "On my way!"

$ shortcuts create "xyz" "XYZ"

$ shortcuts read
0: "xyz" —> "XYZ"
1: "jrv" —> "J’arrive !"
2: "omw" —> "On my way!"

$ shortcuts delete xyz

$ shortcuts read
0: "jrv" —> "J’arrive !"
1: "omw" —> "On my way!"
```

4. Automatically adding Text Replacement entries...

Now we can compose the two utilities to *add* entries to the Text Replacements preferences:

```bsh
$ for p in _42 ^42 _{6..8} ^{9..11}; do
>   ./shortcuts create "${p}" "$(./tsubst "${p}")"
> done

$ ./shortcuts read
0: "^11" —> "¹¹"
1: "^10" —> "¹⁰"
2: "^9" —> "⁹"
3: "_8" —> "₈"
4: "_7" —> "₇"
5: "_6" —> "₆"
6: "^42" —> "⁴²"
7: "_42" —> "₄₂"
8: "jrv" —> "J’arrive !"
9: "omw" —> "On my way!"
```

And the result in the Text Replacements preferences:

[image]

Comment: I actually was working on an answer to the OP, but you posted before I was finish. This is such a good answer I'm not even going to finish mine. +1 -- BTW What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very well-versed with scripting, so I'd appreciate it if you told me exactly what to do.... sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @user3439894 thanks :-) If you have another approach, especially for adding to the text replacements prefs, please don't hesitate  ;-) I tested on Big Sur with a M1 Mac.

Comment: @righter no problem :-) I'll have to get back to you later but I'll add some installation instructions.

Comment: IMO My approach was not as good or even as extensible as yours, I hadn't finished writing it up, and in this particular use case I'm incorporating your answer into my normal usage as I often add items to text substitutions, thru the GUI no more!

Comment: To whomever down-voted this answer, please share why as this answer offers a reasonable way to avoid having to go directly into **System Preferences**  to manage _text substitutions_ and does answer the question asked.

Comment: Well, I found a temporary workaround. Now instead of typing ```^5002```, I type ```^5^0^0^2``` (after manually putting the ten digits in system preferences)

Comment: @righter sorry, I got carried away by the challenge of making that simple bash script easy to install and to use for users unfamiliar with UNIX scripting, while keeping the Q&A and learning approach of Ask Different... :-) I'll start updating my answer in a short while ;-)

Comment: Great job !! Very helpful!!

Comment: @GeorgesMartin Um.... okay? :)